# The relation between potential games and identical interest commutative utility functions

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Assume a graphical game, where the utility of $i$-th player only depends on its neighboring players, i.e. 
$$ u_i(x_i,x_{-i})=u_i(x_i,x_{N(i,1)},...,x_{N(i,M_i)})$$
where: $N(i,j)$ denotes the $j$-th neighboring player to player $i$, and $M_i$ represents the number of players in the neighborhood of player $i$.
We call neighborhood based utility functions commutative if for all $i$:
$$u_i(x_i,x_{-i})=u_i(y) $$ for any permutation $y$ of $x_i,x_{N(i,1)},...,x_{N(i,M_i)}$. 
Consider that all players have identical commutative utility functions. Is this game a potential game, or is there any relations between the two?

Comment: As a matter of fact I have a learning procedure, which i have proved to converge to NE in repeated graphical potential games, now i am trying to prove its convergence for games with commutative utility functions

Comment: Interesting problem. Could you perhaps give an example of such a game? Also when you say all players have identical commutative utility functions, does that mean the functional structure of u is the same for all players?